# xslt:if how to test for boolean values

Tags: xslt

I cannot figure out a way to check if the value of an element is "true" or "false".

It's boolean, converted from a dataset. When I select the value, I see it is either "true" or "false", but my test does not get the expected behaviour. (it is always false.) I tried almost everything, this is my first xslt application, so help is appreciated.

```
      <xsl:if test="ispassive">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <em>pasif değil</em>
            <hr></hr>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:if>
```

Comment: What does ispassive mean? Is it a value for an attribute? Is it an attribute that may or may not be present?

Comment: thx for replies, looks like I misplaced the if conditon, that is why it was failing.
test="ispassive='true'" works in my case.

Comment: Something to consider for future questions: You were referring to an **attribute** value, but were actually evaluating an **element** and it's computed text value. Your description did not exactly match your problem and it would have been easier for us to help you diagnose the problem if you had posted a small example XML and more of the XSLT.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Depending how you represent your booleans it could be a lot of things, what does your data look like?

Most likely scenario, false is represented as 0 and true could be any non 0 value.

```
<xsl:if test="$myvalue = 0">
    -- output if false --
</xsl:if>
```

but you're likely better of using xsl:choose

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$myvalue = 0">
        -- output if false --
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        -- output if true --
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

You can leave out the otherwise, if you don't need it.

Answer (score 21):

After posting here I realized that
my `<xsl:if>` test was outside my `<xsl:for-each>` loop.

After repositioning the `<xsl:if>` conditions, I found out that this works for me.

```
        <xsl:if test="ispassive='true'">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <em>pasif</em>
              <hr></hr>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:if>
```

Comparing the evaluated string value of the `ispassive` element to 'true' works fine, (which I had tried before, but because I misplaced it in the xslt, it was always failing because it failed to select the `ispassive` element to evaluate it's value.

Comment: Your original test criteria was verifying the presence of an `ispassive` element, regardless of it's value. So, as long as there was one present it would return `true()`.  By changing the test to evaluate the **value** of the `ispassive` element, it only returns `true()` if the value is "true".

Answer (score 12):

This xslt is looking for a node in the current context called ispassive.

So if your xml is

```
<Root>
   <ispassive />
</Root>
```

You'll get true. Generally, you should specify an xpath to the value you want to check. So if your xml is

```
<Root>
      <Node ispassive="true"/>
</Root>
```

and you replace

```
<xsl:if test="ispassive">
```

with

```
<xsl:if test="//@ispassive = 'true'">
```

Your stylesheet will work as expected.